# Accept all numbers except 5 consecutive zeros : Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a 5 digit number which should not be 00000. All numbers except 00000 are allowed.

examples : 01201 , 00001, 21436 , 45645 are valid numbers and 1, 12, 123, 1234, 00000 are invalid numbers.

I tried with `^([0-9]{5}[^(0){5}])$` but it was of no use.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what about string.length=5 && string != "00000"? [Edit: OK, testing for numberness requires regex, see @mplungjan's answer]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using negative positive lookahead:

```
/^(?!0{5})\d{5}$/
```

---

```
/^(?!0{5})\d{5}$/.test('01201')
// => true
/^(?!0{5})\d{5}$/.test('00001')
// => true
/^(?!0{5})\d{5}$/.test('21436')
// => true
/^(?!0{5})\d{5}$/.test('1')
// => false
/^(?!0{5})\d{5}$/.test('12')
// => false
/^(?!0{5})\d{5}$/.test('00000')
// => false
```

Comment: Hey this worked like a charm and I upvoted your answer. Only thing I will like to know is how lookahead works in javascript. A brief explanation or a simple tutorial link will be helpful for me.

Comment: @NareshRavlani, Reading [Regex Tutorial - Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will be helpful.

Comment: Negative lookahed is JS 1.5 so you might want to test if it works in your suppported browsers

Answer (score 8):

No need for negative lookahead

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/u4F7M/)

```
function isvalid5(str) {
  return str != "00000" && /^\d{5}$/.test(str);
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your regex, it should start with `^` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a negative look ahead:

```
^(?!0{5})\d{5}$
```

The negative loo ahead `(?!...)` will fail the whole regex if what's inside it matches, `\d` is a shortcut for `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 2):

for regex engines that do not support lookahead:

```
^(0000[1-9]|000[1-9][0-9]|00[1-9][0-9]{2}|0[1-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{4})$
```